# Gradle will pass in CLI and not Intellij (Instance method doesn't exist)

Tags: java, gradle, avro

I run tests on CI and local and they pass with `gradle test`. When I run via Intellij or try to debug, they fail and I get a failure on this call:

`LogicalType type = schema.getLogicalType();` This is actually an external function call in one of our dependencies.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.avro.LogicalType org.apache.avro.Schema.getLogicalType()'

I'm not sure how to get around this, is this conflicting jars on the classpath?

Dependency graph on Avro

```
❯ gradle dependencies | grep -i avro
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    \--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    \--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.0 -> 1.9.1 (*)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:5.3.1
|    +--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
     \--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1 (n)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:5.3.1 (n)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.0 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.0 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:5.3.1
|    |    +--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.2 -> 5.3.1 (*)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1 (*)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:5.3.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    \--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    \--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.0 -> 1.9.1 (*)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:5.3.1
|    +--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    \--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.0 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.0 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:5.3.1
|    |    +--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1 -> 1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.1 (*)
|    +--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.2 -> 5.3.1 (*)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.1 (*)
+--- io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:5.3.1 (*)
```

Comment: How exactly are you running/debuging this test in Intellij? Are us using Gradle run configuration? What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: 2019.3.3 community edition. "build and run" set to gradle "build" set to gradle as well.

Comment: I've tried various combinations of this config

Answer (score 0):

It look like you have two different versions of Avro on classpath. Try to list dependencies with Gradle (see [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies)) - you may see the problem there.

Edit:

It seems your app is indirectly dependent on Avro 1.7.7, 1.8.1, 1.9.0 and 1.9.1.

You should use dependency constraints to make sure your're using only one version.

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html) for details.

Comment: I've added the graph to the OP. Do you have suggestions for what I should do as this looks pretty bad in terms of conflicts.